# python script breaks output lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, command-line, io

If I run

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1]) # note to self: argv[0] is script file content

description = df.groupby(['option','subcase']).describe()
totals = df.groupby('option').describe().set_index(np.array(['total'] * df['option'].nunique()), append=True)
description = description.append(totals).sort_index()
print(description)
```

on `.csv`

```
option,subcase,cost,time
A,sub1,4,3
A,sub1,2,0
A,sub2,3,8
A,sub2,1,2
B,sub1,13,0
B,sub1,11,0
B,sub2,5,2
B,sub2,3,4
```

, I get an output like this:

```
                cost                                                  time  \
               count  mean       std   min    25%   50%    75%   max count   
option subcase                                                               
A      sub1      2.0   3.0  1.414214   2.0   2.50   3.0   3.50   4.0   2.0   
       sub2      2.0   2.0  1.414214   1.0   1.50   2.0   2.50   3.0   2.0   
       total     4.0   2.5  1.290994   1.0   1.75   2.5   3.25   4.0   4.0   
B      sub1      2.0  12.0  1.414214  11.0  11.50  12.0  12.50  13.0   2.0   
       sub2      2.0   4.0  1.414214   3.0   3.50   4.0   4.50   5.0   2.0   
       total     4.0   8.0  4.760952   3.0   4.50   8.0  11.50  13.0   4.0   


                mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max  
option subcase                                             
A      sub1     1.50  2.121320  0.0  0.75  1.5  2.25  3.0  
       sub2     5.00  4.242641  2.0  3.50  5.0  6.50  8.0  
       total    3.25  3.403430  0.0  1.50  2.5  4.25  8.0  
B      sub1     0.00  0.000000  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  
       sub2     3.00  1.414214  2.0  2.50  3.0  3.50  4.0  
       total    1.50  1.914854  0.0  0.00  1.0  2.50  4.0
```

This is annoying, especially if you want to save it as a `.csv` instead of displaying it in a console.

(e.g. `python myscript.py my.csv > my.summary`)

How do I stop this linebreak from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding : [`pd.set_option`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html)

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)

print(description)
                cost                                                  time                                           
               count  mean       std   min    25%   50%    75%   max count  mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max
option subcase                                                                                                       
A      sub1      2.0   3.0  1.414214   2.0   2.50   3.0   3.50   4.0   2.0  1.50  2.121320  0.0  0.75  1.5  2.25  3.0
       sub2      2.0   2.0  1.414214   1.0   1.50   2.0   2.50   3.0   2.0  5.00  4.242641  2.0  3.50  5.0  6.50  8.0
       total     4.0   2.5  1.290994   1.0   1.75   2.5   3.25   4.0   4.0  3.25  3.403430  0.0  1.50  2.5  4.25  8.0
B      sub1      2.0  12.0  1.414214  11.0  11.50  12.0  12.50  13.0   2.0  0.00  0.000000  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0
       sub2      2.0   4.0  1.414214   3.0   3.50   4.0   4.50   5.0   2.0  3.00  1.414214  2.0  2.50  3.0  3.50  4.0
       total     4.0   8.0  4.760952   3.0   4.50   8.0  11.50  13.0   4.0  1.50  1.914854  0.0  0.00  1.0  2.50  4.0
```